# key press to change a bool? what is the best practice?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, keyboard, keypress

I have a TreeView and a multiline TextBox. When user clicks on a node in the treeview, it's `Text` property will be added to the TextBox.

By default, everytime that a node is clicked (or hitting enter when treeview has focus and that sort of stuff...), the TextBox will be cleared and the new `Text` of the selected node will be added.

But I am looking for a way, that when user holds a modifier key (ctrl or shift...) the textbox will not be cleared and the newly selected node's text will be added to the textbox without clearing anything.

I am thinking about having a boolean, and whenever the modifier key is pressed, it changes to false and when the key is released it gets back to true.

```
public bool ClearBox = true;
```

Later:

```
private void AddText(string text)
{
   if(ClearBox == true) //by default it is true
   {
      textBox.Clear();
      textBox.Text = text;
   }
   else //user is holding a modifier key so the ClearBox is false now
   {
      textBox += Environment.NewLine + text;
   }
}
```

Node select event:

```
private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
   //How to check here if a modifire key is being pressed (holded) ?
   this.AddText(treeView.SelectedNode.Text);
}
```

Comment: The question is how can I know the user is holding a modifier key, so the textbox does not referesh itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the property `ModifierKeys` of the form which modifier key is pressed. In your code you would have to do like this:

```
private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) 
{
    if (ModifierKeys == Keys.ShiftKey)
    {
        this.AddText(treeView.SelectedNode.Text); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Can I use the same way to toggle the `ClearBox` to true/false? I mean if it is a reliable way to do so?

Comment: You can ask this property for the modifier keys (Alt, Ctrl and Shift) and nothing else. You can toggle that property, but there is no event raised right in the moment the user presses a modifier key. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it was helpful to you. :-)